# About this Javascript Code Construct

Tags: javascript

I am currently debugging some code right now but I cant get myself around this concept in javascript.

```
I have this code construct.
if(!COMPANY)
    COMPANY = {};

COMPANY.Billing = (function(COMPANY){
    //More code
})(COMPANY);
```

As, i understand, it creates an object called "COMPANY" and then adds a new property called "Billing"
but I dont understand the idea of passing the same "COMPANY" into the arguments of the function and at the
same time renaming it to "COMPANY" again.  What I mean is what is the difference between the code above
and the  code below.

```
COMPANY.Billing = (function(COMPANY){
    //More code
})();
```

My javascript is not that deep so I would like to understand what the code construct above means.  This might be some javascript design pattern but I dont know what it is

Comment: Try reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1) on How Closures Work. It might help you.

Comment: You just made COMPANY undefined inside that function.

Comment: The difference is in the second code block you are not passing anything to the anonymous function. It will change the inner code behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't renaming `COMPANY`; it's using it. Annotated version of your code:

```
if(!COMPANY)            // if COMPANY doesn't exist...
    COMPANY = {};       // initialize it to a blank object

COMPANY.Billing =       // initialize a property
    (function(COMPANY){ // this defines a function
        //More code
    })(COMPANY);        // this executes the function with COMPANY as the parameter
// COMPANY.Billing now contains the result of executing the anonymous function
```

This is called a closure. Example:

```
foo = (function(x) {
    return ++x;
})(4);
```

This defines a function, then executes with parameter `x = 4`. So, it returns `++x`, which is 5. Therefore, `foo` is assigned the value 5.

When you do this:

```
COMPANY.Billing = (function(COMPANY){
    //More code
})();
```

You are defining a closure and executing it, but you are passing nothing as a parameter. So, `COMPANY` is undefined inside the closure.

Comment: Oh wow...that fast..so in my first case, the same object that I have declared above is passed as argument to the anonymous function?  I wonder why you need to do this, as I have been reading, the COMPANY variable is global in scope so why not access it directly inside the anonymous function?  Sorry if my question might be vague but I just want to understand further.  Your post answers some of my doubts. Thanks.

Comment: There is a variable `COMPANY` that is global in scope, but naming your parameter `COMPANY` is as though you have `var COMPANY` inside the function. To reuse my example above, say you have `x=6; foo = (function(x) { return ++x; })();`
Then `foo` is `NaN`, because the global `x` and the `x` used in the closure are different.

Comment: Oh thank you very much.  I think I got my much needed headstart to debug these files of javascript.  Your explanation really really helps me understand the concept. More power to you!